# using jList in NetBeans JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlist, mouselistener

I've added new component to my project: JFrame.
I've added JList, but I don't know how to use it.
Ona of examples I've found was adding MouseListener, but I dunno how and where to use it.

```
public class ListaKarolci extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public ListaKarolci() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                         
     DefaultListModel przyklad= new DefaultListModel();

    for(int i=0; i< 20; i++)
        przyklad.addElement(i+1);

    jList1.setModel(przyklad);

}                                        


public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ListaKarolci().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JList jList1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**My question is: how can I get action (for example double click) performed on jList?**

/***************************************************************/
Since I can anwser this question since it's closed I've found the anwser:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
if(e.getClickCount() == 2){
 int index = jList1.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
 ListModel dlm = jList1.getModel();
 Object item = dlm.getElementAt(index);;
 jList1.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Double clicked on "+item);
 }
}
```

Comment: You haven't yet asked a specific answerable question. Please edit your question to improve it. About the only recommendation I can give you based on what you've posted is for you to read the [JList tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: I've asked the question, now I've made it bold. Moreover I've added solution that I found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: how can I get action (for example double click) performed on jList?

Check out [List Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/) for a general approach that allows you to add an Action to a JList.